# Flutter ios push notification issue

Tags: flutter, firebase, push-notification

Flutter ios firebase push notification works well on simulator or browserstack, but it does not works on real IOS device.

I am using APNs Auth Key. IPhone 13., ios version 17.
After upload testflight, It works well on broswerstack or simulator, but it does not work on real device.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For your problem I recommend you to check these differents points:

1. Ensure push notifications are enabled in your app's capabilities on Xcode.
2. Verify that your provisionning profile that includes push notifications for real device testing.
3. Make sure notifications are enabled for your app in the device's settings.
4. Check your Firebase setup matches the correct APNs environment.
5. On the iOS device, try resetting network settings to fix APNs connection issues.

You can find some extra information to help you to find your problem https://firebase.blog/posts/2017/01/debugging-firebase-cloud-messaging-on

I hope this will help you.